# %load_ext rpy2.ipython causes "The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically"

Tags: python, r, jupyter, rpy2, macos-mojave

In a jupyter notebook

```
%load_ext rpy2.ipython
```

causes the kernel to crash.

> "The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically."

with the following console message

```
Error in `::`(base, quote) : could not find function "::"
Error in `::`(base, quote) : could not find function "::"
Error in `:::`(compiler, checkCompilerOptions) : 
  could not find function ":::"
Fatal error: unable to initialize the JIT
```

Any clues on this? I've tried cleaning out my R installation and starting from scratch. Same error, every time.

Mac OS 10.14.6
python 3.8
R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
rpy2-3.4.4
jupyter-1.0.0

Comment: You may want to add `python3 -m rpy2.situation` output.

Comment: When you start the R interpreter from command line, does it work?

Comment: R starts fine...R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18) -- "Camp Pontanezen"
Copyright (C) 2021 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)

Comment: `python3 -m rpy2.situation`
`/opt/local/bin/python3: Error while finding module specification for 'rpy2.situation' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rpy2')`

Comment: ```pip install rpy2
Requirement already satisfied: rpy2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (3.4.4)```

Comment: Maybe your executable has a different name? E.g. `python`?

Comment: `/usr/local/lib/python3.8 -m rpy2.situation` should work then

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @krassowski my python38 installation was messed up. Uninstalled python and all packages installed by pip and started again with python39. Fixed the problem.